# Why I could not get a full result with VBA for-loop

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

In the excel file as above, I want each words in the Column one (12 totally) and each words in the Column two (4 totally) to be combined into phrases generated in the Column three. I should get 12*4 = 48 phrases. Using the codes I wrote as below, only less than 30 are there with some null-value cells. Please tell me why I couldn't reach 48. Thank you.

```
Sub WordsCombiner()
    For i = 1 To 12
        For m = 1 To 4
            Cells(i * m, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(m, 2).Value
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The following is the original words:

***(Column one)***

```
from
the 
on 
this 
Oh
and 
FYI 
prices 
accurate 
and 
items 
in
```

***Column Two***

```
as 
time 
of 
publication
```

Comment: It's because of this `Cells(i * m, 3).Value`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Sub WordsCombiner()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 12

        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To 4

            Dim k As Long
            k = k + 1
            Cells(k, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(j, 2).Value
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh didn't notice the string concantenation thing - good fix. Nice clean answer, though I'm a bit tempted to edit it to put the `Dim` together outside the loop. :0

Comment: always declare you variables before you use them, that way you know when you started using them ;) comes in handy when you're dealing with hundreds lines of code

Comment: or omit Option Explict so there is no need to bother with it :p

Comment: I assum every module has an automatic `Option Explicit` declaration. If not then at least my code provided won't fail due to the variables...

Comment: as you should of course. could an answer here even seriously recommend not using Option Explicit without getting edited and the author receiving public shaming?

Comment: @alowflyingpig Avoid using implicit references like`Cell` what is implicit referencing`ActiveSheet` See [Avoiding implicit code](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/tag/implicit/) and  [code-name-sheet1](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is dynamic so it will run for every value in `Column A` and `Column B`. It also ads the space between the groupings as you have shown in your output.

*lra = last row column a*
*lrb = last row column b*
*i = counter for column c*

```
Sub Combine()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim lra As Long, lrb As Long, a As Long, b As Long
Dim i As Long: i = 1

lra = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrb = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For b = 1 To lrb

    For a = 1 To lra
        ws.Range("C" & i) = ws.Range("A" & a) & Chr(32) & ws.Range("B" & b)
        i = i + 1 '<--Next Row on Column C
    Next a

    i = i + 1 '<--Add Space Between Groupings 

Next b


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic for assigning the result row is wrong. When you have `i * m` you get that for both "from time" and "the as" since 1*2 and 2*1 both = 2. Either use a separate counter variable or change the expression. Best way to figure this out is define three sets of values and the row they should be and find what fits.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer SQL for that task.

```sql
Select 
  t1.Col1, t2.col2 , t1.col1 & " " & t2.col2 
FROM 
  (Select col1 From [Sheet1$] WHERE col1 Is Not Null) as t1,
  (Select col2 From [Sheet1$] WHERE col2 Is Not Null) as t2
```

That query creates a carthesian product of both columns-

The result contains all combination of column1 and column2.. If the columns contain dupes and you dön't want repeating results, just use

```sql
Select Distinct t1.col1 & " " & t2.col2 As Result ...
```

to get rid of them.

Here's an Example, to convince the downvoter and the loopers of the simple beautiness of SQL when working with data:

```vb
Private Sub ComputeCarthesianProduct()
Dim sql As String
sql = "Select t1.[F1]  & ' ' & t2.[F2] As Result FROM " _
  & " (Select [F1] From [Sheet1$] WHERE [F1]  Is Not Null) as t1," _
  & " (Select [F2]  From [Sheet1$] WHERE [F2] Is Not Null) as t2"
Debug.Print sql

Dim con As Object
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With con
    .Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;Imex=1;HDR=no"";" 
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Open sql, con
        Sheet1.Range("C1").CopyFromRecordset rs 'Sheet1 is CodeName of Worksheets("Sheet1"). An explicit reference, immune to renaming the sheet
        .Close
    End With 
    .Close
End With
End Sub
```

If you still prefer to nest one loop for each column, you deserve to get dizzy ;)

Comment: can't understand why this was downvoted. these kinds of query of very fast and useful in excel files